# Red Box is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have install the Red box plugin by using the  following command

script/plugin install svn://rubyforge.org/var/svn/ambroseplugins/redbox .

It installed successfully. and again ran the following command the following location

/myapp/vendor/plugin/redbox/rake update_scripts . It shows me the following output

(in /myapp/vendor/plugins/redbox)
rake aborted!
private method `copy' called for File:Class
/home/myapp/vendor/plugins/redbox/Rakefile:28
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

I don't know How to solve this ... Then i understand that "rake update_scripts" copying the Js and Css file only. so i manually copied the Redbox.js & redbox.css files into the respective places  under /public folder

I include the follwoing into my application.html.erb

It included in the page successfully. The following is my view code :

{:action=> 'log'} ,:method =>'get') %>

The popup box doesn't appear. I have no clue what is the exact error. Is that any Jquery clash?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly, redbox helper adds hidden div close to where you call whatever_redbox(), you can inspect the html and see if it is properly generated. The hidden div is important because that is where your lightbox is generated.